# Contracting a segment in a Lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

Studying lattices, I'm looking for the following construction:

Given a finite (hence bounded and complete) lattice $L$ and $a,b \in L$ such that $a\leq b$,
obtain a lattice $L'$ by "contracting" the segment $[a,b]$ into one point.

There should be a homomorphism frrom $L$ to $L'$. I believe this can be describe by the equivalence classes induced by
$$
x \sim
    \begin{cases}
        & x \lor b \text{ if } a \leq  x\\
        & x \land a \text{ if } x \leq  b\\
        & x \lor \neg a \text{ if } \neg b \leq  x\\
        & x \land \neg b \text{ if } x \leq  \neg a
    \end{cases}
$$
But showing this is well defined seems rather inelegant, especially since in my casew the lattice is complemented and I have twice as many cases. I also believe this is the result one obtains from taking the presentation of $L$ (all inequalities) and adding $a=b$ to it. This obviously induces an homomorphism to the free algebra induced by the presentation, but then I have no idea how to show that the resulting lattice is non trivial ($1\neq 0$).

It seems that this "contraction" construction would have to be standard, some kind of inverse Day's doubling procedure, but I've found no reference about it.

Comment: Isn't this just making $L'=L/\theta$ where $\theta$ is the principal congruence generated by $(a,b)$, that is, the least congruence which relates $a$ to $b$?

Comment: Yes, most likely, but how do you show the resulting lattice is non-trivial? It doesn't hold in general without $a\leq b$

Comment: It may be trivial. For example, if $a\vee b=1$ and $a\wedge b=0$, then it's certainly trivial. But you're referring to an interval $[a,b]$, where necessarily $a\leq b$; even in this case, $L'$, may be trivial, for example, if $L$ is simple, such as $M_3$, or any partition lattice. By the way, your displayed formula doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: Well, you also certainly need the condition $a \neq 0$ or $b\neq 1$.
I'd expect that such a contraction in $M_3$ (e.g. of $[0, x]$, for $x$ one of the middle element) yields the 2-elements lattice.

Comment: No, if $M_3=\{0,a,b,c,1\}$, and $(0,a)\in\theta$ then $(b,1)=(0\vee b,a\vee b)\in\theta$, whence $(0,c)=(b\wedge c,1\wedge c)\in\theta$, yielding $(0,1)=(0\vee 0,a\vee c)\in\theta$. Now, if $0$ and $1$ are congruent, then all of them are, since congruence classes on lattices are convex subsets (actually convex sub-lattices). So $|M_3/\theta|=1$, unless $\theta=\{(x,x):x\in M_3\}$. The same applies with $M_3$ replaced by any partition lattice ($M_3$ is the partition lattice on a 3-element set).

Comment: You're right indeed, thank you. Any idea what might be the weakest condition for which this would hold? In my case, I can assume for example $L$ does not contain $M_3$ as a sublattice, and that $a. b \not\in\lbrace0, 1\rbrace$. The construction would yield a non-trivial lattice if $L$ is $N_5$ or $O_6$ for example.
And I suppose you haven't heard of a reference for a similar construction?

Comment: Simplest one is probably that all points in the lattice are either between $a$ and $b$ or incomparable to both.

Comment: I mentioned a congruence relation because you wrote that there should be a homomorphism from $h:L\to L'$. In case $L'$ is the quotient of $L$ by a congruence relation, then $h$ can even be surjective and $\ker h=\theta$, the congruence. There is nothing wrong with this approach, unless this doesn't give the result you wish; and perhaps that will depend on the lattice and choice of $a$ and $b$. So it seems to me that you need a different approach, then you should give a better description of what you want.

Comment: This might be possible if for $x\notin[a,b]$ and $a<c<b$ if $x<c$ then $x<a$ and if $c<x$ then $b<x$. The meaning is that there are no coverings between elements of $]a,b[$ and elements from outside $[a,b]$ (where $]a,b[=\{c:a<c<b\}$). This would mean that $L$ results from $L'$ by a construction which generalizes Alan Day's one (instead of just doubling, replaces each element by a finite lattice). The details would depend on the exact problem.

Comment: Indeed that is what I was suspecting, but I'm unsure if I can afford such a property on $L$. Thank you for your help